# How to share an editable android project with git and sourcetree

Tags: android, eclipse, git, atlassian-sourcetree

I need to share an android project with another pc and still be able to edit it on both sides.
For some reason I can't get this to work. I have tried a lot of different combinations to import it and still be able to edit and push changes.
When I try to import the project into my workspace, there is a lot of errors like this:

```
the type java.lang.object cannot be resolved. it is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Then I tried importing the JRE System library (JRE 7)
After doing this I still get errors. for example this:

```
Activity cannot be resolved
```

Then I imported the Android library to the project (API 18). But after doing this, there is a red cross on the project, but not in any classes, files or like..

Therefore I tried to clean the project, which removed the "R.java" and gave me a bunch more errors.

I don't know exactly what I am doing wrong here so I hope someone can help me out.

What is the "right" way to import eclipse projects and still be able to edit and push/pull?

(Btw. I am using BitBucket and SourceTree and trying to import it into my eclipse workspace. )

Comment: What is the error or problem?

Comment: "But after doing this, there is a red cross on the project, but not in any classes, files or like" -> in Eclipse, what does the Problems view tell you? (if it's not open, use Window > Show view > Problems)

Comment: Found out what was wrong. The Window > Show view > Problems showed that the necessary API wasn't available at that eclipse version. So I downloaded it and then it worked. Thanks for your help LoicAG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what was wrong. 
By navigating to "Window > Show view > Problems", I found out that the necessary API wasn't available at that eclipse version. So I downloaded it the software and it worked.